Share database between Next.js and Expo
I'm working on a Next.js web app and I was planning to create a mobile application for it using Expo. I wanted to share the authentication and database between the web app and the mobile app. The best solution I found was to use Supabase and deploy the web app on Vercel, but the problem is the now I'll to subscribe for both Supabase and Vercel without actually using most of Vercel's features (as it provides authentication and database).
So the question is can I share my Vercel Postgres database and Next Auth with the Expo app?
